# no library found for namespace http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink JSF

Tags: jsf, xhtml, xlink

I am trying to add two icons on my login page. When I try to add a library, the jsf shows an error "no library found for namespace http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<h:body class="align">
    <div class="grid">
        <form action="https://httpbin.org/post" method="POST" class="form login">
            <img class="logo" src="resources/img/logo%20mailing.png"/> 
            <div class="form__field">
                <label for="login__username"><svg class="icon">
                        <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#user"></use>
                    </svg><span class="hidden">Usuário</span></label>
                <input id="login__username" type="text" name="username" class="form__input" placeholder="Usuário" required="true"/>
            </div>
</form>
</div>
</h:body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved

I needed to change from `xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"` to `xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"`

and from here `<use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#user"></use>` to `<use xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" href="#user"></use>`